# Change code to pull additional data from site

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I am pulling data from a website but need assistance to pull the entire string.

Example:

[image: Example]

I have tried to look into the website source code to understand it but with different changes yield bad results

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, csrft As String, lastRow As Long, sourceValues() '<  VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft HTML Object Library
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    sourceValues = ws.Range("B2:D" & lastRow).Value
    Dim results()
    ReDim results(1 To UBound(sourceValues, 1), 1 To 4)
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.partstown.com", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText

        csrft = html.querySelector("[name=CSRFToken]").Value
        Stop
        For i = LBound(sourceValues, 1) To UBound(sourceValues, 1)
            If sourceValues(i, 1) <> vbNullString And sourceValues(i, 3) <> vbNullString Then
                DoEvents
                .Open "POST", "https://www.partstown.com/track-my-order", False
                .setRequestHeader "Referer", "https://www.partstown.com/track-my-order"
                .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
                .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                .setRequestHeader "Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"
                .setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate"
                .setRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9"
                .send "orderNo=" & sourceValues(i, 1) & "&postalCode=" & sourceValues(i, 3) & "&CSRFToken=" & csrft

                html.body.innerHTML = .responseText

                Dim shipping As String, order As String, items() As String

                shipping = html.querySelector("[data-label=Shipping]").innerText
                order = html.querySelector(".order-history__item-descript--min").innerText
                items = Split(order, vbNewLine)

                Dim qtyOrdered As Long, qtyShipped As String, product As String

                qtyOrdered = CLng(Replace$(items(0), "Qty Ordered: ", vbNullString))
                qtyShipped = CLng(Replace$(items(1), "Qty Shipped: ", vbNullString))
                product = html.querySelector(".details-table a").Title

                results(i, 1) = shipping
                results(i, 2) = qtyOrdered
                results(i, 3) = qtyShipped
                results(i, 4) = product
            End If
            'Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
        Next
    End With
    'results written out from row 2 column E
    ws.Cells(2, 5).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results

End Sub
```

I input a PO and zip (4500987740 and 33314) that contains multiple parts, the data returned is only the first part, not all the parts.

Example 2:

[image: example 2]

I need to return all data:
Tracking, qty ordered, qty shipped, product, qty ordered, qty shipped product, etc - basically as a string until all parts are displayed

Comment: Edited to try and make more poignant.

Comment: your code as posted above with values 4500987740 and 33314 - are you saying that produces the output in example 2?

Comment: Yes that is correct, what I would like is for it to string all the values not just the top line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the use of `querySelector`. [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns the first match only. In this case it means you are only ever considering the first
row. The required amendment is to use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to return all matches. Then loop those matches to extract each row's info.

Additionally, this selector `.details-table a`  must be altered to only return items of interest i.e. to `.details-table a[title]` - those that have a
`title` attribute.

To write out to each row appropriately a helper function is used to find the next free row. As the row count is not known in advance an array of the appropriate size cannot be set to house all results - though you could oversize the array from the start. That latter point is an amendment you could make. I instead loop writing out arrays in batches.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, csrft As String, ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, wsTarget As Worksheet, j As Long '<  VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft HTML Object Library
    Dim sourceValues()

    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")
    Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    sourceValues = ws.Range("B2:D" & lastRow).Value

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.partstown.com", False
        .send

        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText

        csrft = html.querySelector("[name=CSRFToken]").Value
        For j = LBound(sourceValues, 1) To UBound(sourceValues, 1)
            If sourceValues(j, 1) <> vbNullString And sourceValues(j, 3) <> vbNullString Then
                DoEvents
                .Open "POST", "https://www.partstown.com/track-my-order", False
                .setRequestHeader "Referer", "https://www.partstown.com/track-my-order"
                .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
                .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                .setRequestHeader "Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"
                .setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate"
                .setRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9"
                .send "orderNo=" & sourceValues(j, 1) & "&postalCode=" & sourceValues(j, 3) & "&CSRFToken=" & csrft
                html.body.innerHTML = .responseText

                Dim shipping As String, orders As Object, items() As String

                shipping = html.querySelector("[data-label=Shipping]").innerText
                Set orders = html.querySelectorAll(".order-history__item-descript--min")

                Dim i As Long, c As Long, results(), products As Object
                ReDim results(1 To 1, 1 To 4 * orders.length)
                Dim qtyOrdered As Long, qtyShipped As String, product As String
                Set products = html.querySelectorAll(".details-table a[title]")
                c = 1
                For i = 0 To orders.length - 1
                    items = Split(orders.item(i).innerText, vbNewLine)
                    qtyOrdered = CLng(Replace$(items(0), "Qty Ordered: ", vbNullString))
                    qtyShipped = CLng(Replace$(items(1), "Qty Shipped: ", vbNullString))
                    results(1, c) = shipping
                    results(1, c + 1) = qtyOrdered
                    results(1, c + 2) = qtyShipped
                    results(1, c + 3) = products.item(i).Title
                    c = c + 4
                Next
                wsTarget.Cells(GetLastRow(wsTarget) + 1, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long
    With ws
        GetLastRow = .Cells(.rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thats actually really close. is there a way to have them string left to right?  https://imgur.com/YJ8bzAs

Comment: what do you mean? I am writing them row per row.

Comment: I included a link to for a screen shot

Comment: Change the function to a find last column function and add one. Then  switch  wsTarget.Cells(GetLastRow(wsTarget) + 1, 1)  to wsTarget.Cells(1, GetLastColumn(1))

Comment: Ok so now what that does is shift the row it places those on to the right of the data, I think what I am asking is this. is there a way to take the vertical data, and have it pasted horizontally as to correspond with each PO and Zip code?  like the screenshot depicts? https://imgur.com/qz4ekcj  I promise Im not trying to make this hard

Comment: I'm tired. Rather than arrows it would help more if you simply showed the same data in the desired output format. P.S. I probably won't get round to update until tomorrow.

Comment: I'm sorry I just thought it might be helpful to illustrate :/

Comment: It probably is but my eyes are crossed with tiredness.

Comment: You have all the elements that you need so you could have a go at it and we can revisit tomorrow.

Comment: Actually, that one gives me an error for some reason Error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error. Get some rest, I can also play with this and see if I can make it work

Comment: Hummm... ran for me. Which line?

Comment: Line 59 is the one it highlights when i debug

Comment: nevermind I fixed that, issue was with formatting. runtime error 91 happens on line 34, thought i could make it work with on error resume next but then nothing happens at all. Code =                                                                              
     shipping = html.querySelector("[data-label=Shipping]").innerText

Comment: Check your values in sheet are being picked up correctly and they are valid and have no white space either side

Comment: I checked the values and they are correct now. I am back to getting Error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error.  Code being:  GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: Unsure as can't reproduce. I am testing with https://tmpfiles.org/download/19235/Book1.xlsb

Comment: was that file helpful?

Comment: It was perfect, sorry IT did a pushed update to my computer that took it down a few days. Man you are so helpful!! Thank you for all your help and support

Comment: Not a problem :-)